# QPrinter's PDF data, how to grab it?

Tags: c++, pdf, qt5

As the title says, how do i grab the internal PDF data from QPrinter without going the extra mile of outputting to a temporary file and reading that in for further processing?

I have checked the documentation and found nothing what would let me do something like

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);

QTextDocument doc;    
doc.setHtml("<p>Test me!</p>");
doc.print(&printer);

QByteArray foo = printer.data();
```

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know would be by using QTemporaryFile

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
QTemporaryFile pdf;
pdf.open();
printer.setOutputFileName(pdf.fileName());

QTextDocument doc;    
doc.setHtml("<p>Test me!</p>");
doc.print(&printer);

QByteArray foo = pdf.readAll();
```

Comment: Nice idea, but not what i am looking for. :)